# How to use Github with VSC

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, git-commit

I am a mac user new to github and visual studio code, so I apologize if I missed something obvious.

My problem is that after reading the official docs, I cannot figure out how to actual get github to work with Visual Studio Code.

First of all, I have repositories set up on github, but when I try to access them, this happens:
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could it be perhaps caused by the fact that my repositories on Github are private?

So I ended up manually inserting the link and cloning the repository.

In my new repository, I created a new file called testfile, and wrote a message in it. I would like to commit this to github.
When I click on the git button this happens:

[image]

I am confused specifically by what exactly Untracked means. Again, I apologize if this sounds obvious to you. I am new to github.
After looking at the docs, I realized that I have to go to this location:

[image]

I still cannot find how to commit my local repository. I tried searching for the keyword "commit" on the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github), but didn't find any ways to do so. I also tried watching various youtube videos on the topic, but all the videos involve clicking on a check mark

[image]

that I cannot find in my version of VSC.

Additionally, I tried pulling changes I made to my repository elsewhere, but after clicking on the "+" button next to pull requests, I am stuck doing this:

[image]

Any help or links to resources would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Nothing to do with github. Nothing to do with VSC.  It’s git. The workflow is edit, add, commit (and maybe push). Untracked means you edited but did not yet add.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a terminal for git workflows instead of VSC. Its much easier and gives you a better understanding of git also.

Comment: @leoOrion Do you have any resources on using terminal with git? Also, is there an easy way to upload VSC code to github with terminal? That is my end goal after all.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-the-basics-of-git-in-under-10-minutes-da548267cc91/

Comment: git does not care abt vsc or any other editor. The commands are same regardless of what you use to code.

Comment: The link you sent is really hopeful, thanks